# How do I get an access token from Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: node.js, azure, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently dealing with the fascinatingly confusing world of Microsoft. I've read several of the half-baked tutorials on how to use their Graph API and Office 365 API and I still don't really know what to do. What I HAVE figure out is how to build that authorization request URL so I can get the "code", which is supposed to be used to then get the access token. I've done this with the Google API and it works beautifully, but not with the Microsoft Graph API. Here's what I have:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=123451234512345&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.my-site.com/oauth-callback/microsoft
```

When the user clicks on this link, they are taken to the Microsoft login page. So far, so good. But, after entering my login credentials it just takes me right back to the same Microsoft login page, as opposed to redirecting the user to my redirect uri. I have an Azure account with the same redirect URI specified, but it just isn't working. What am I doing wrong? By the way, I'm using node.js. Any links to useful tutorials would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a code you need to pass the following parameters:

- response_type=code
- client_id=yourClientId
- redirect_uri=yourRedirectUri
- resource=https://graph.microsoft.com

For example:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=12334&redirect_uri=https://myapp.com&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com

Finally, thank you for the feedback, can you please point the articles you read where the information was not clear so we can make sure to update them? I suggest you try the following article: https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/platform/rest

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still does the same thing. I am taken to the authentication page, I enter my password, then I'm redirected here: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf" instead of my redirect URI.

Comment: One thing that is uniquely odd about using the Microsoft API is how I need to create an outlook business account, then create an Azure account. Then, I am supposed to link the outlook account to the Azure account. Next, I have to create an Active Directory and an bunch of other weird stuff - before I write any code at all. With Google, I just simply use my gmail account and create the API keys. Done. Why make it so complicated just to get started?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great video explaining the login process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOcwvuIJHXA "Deep Dive into the Office 365 RESTful APIs". It is very long, but detailed. Around 25:00 it shows with Fiddler how the login works. Helped me a lot.